# Using lapply to count values in a single column in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, lapply

I am trying to calculate the percent occurence of specific values in a single column of a dataframe. I use the following code to load a single dataframe, and calculate the total count of each value within the sinlge column "Counter". Then, I divide it by the number of rows present in that dataframe, to get percentages.

```
test <- read.csv("./subdata/Bur01.csv")
test %>%
  group_by(Counter) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length(Counter))

  Counter no_rows
    <int>   <int>
1       2     176
2       5      49
3       7     343


table(test$Counter)/length(test$Counter)


     2          5          7 
0.30985915 0.08626761 0.60387324
```

However, I have 187 dataframes that all have the same structure (as in, column headers) but a different set of values in the "Counter" column. I load them all into a Large List of 187 elements (named myfiles) as such:

```
temp <- list.files(path = "./subdata", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

Would I be able to code a function or loop that can give me the percent occurrence of the values only in the 'Counter' column of each individual dataframe, without having to go through and do each one seperately?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!

Simply apply your function to each data.frame via `lapply`:

```
props = lapply(myfiles, counter_props)
```

Where `counter_props` is:

```
counter_props = function (df) {
    prop.table(df$Counter)
}
```

… but of course you don’t really need to define a named function for this if this is the only use of this logic:

```
props = lapply(myfiles, function (df) prop.table(df$Counter))
```

You could also write the entire thing in a pipeline by splitting apart the different steps of this computation (using the ‘purrr’ package):

```
props = myfiles %>%
    map(pull, Counter) %>%
    map(table) %>%
    map(prop.table)
```

(Note that `prop.table` effectively does the same as dividing the table by the total length.)